# Consider all possible orderings of the numbers from $1$ to $10$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider all possible orderings of the numbers from $1$ to $10$. For such
an ordering, a number is lucky if it appears in the same position as in the usual order. Assuming all orderings have the same probability, compute the expected number of lucky numbers in a random ordering.

For this question, I was able to find the right answer by constructing the bijective mapping.

Is there any way that this question can be done in probability theory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The chance that any given number is lucky is $\frac1{10}$. Then, by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), the total expected number of lucky numbers is $10\left(\frac1{10}\right) = 1$.

Comment: when it says orderings, is 2222222222 acceptable?

Comment: @jessie No, an ordering is a permutation, i.e., every number from  $1$ to $10$ will appear exactly once.

Comment: If that's the case, how would you know that each one has 1/10 chance of hitting the right place? for example, if you 2 on the first place, there is no probability of hitting the right place on the second place

Comment: @jessie That is where linearity of expectation comes in: it doesn't matter whether the events are dependent or independent. To put this another way, if you write out all $10!$ permutations of $[1,10]$, then each number appears equally often in every position. More feasibly, try doing this with $n=3$ or $4$ rather than $10$ to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

It's always $1$.

Standard argument: Let $E_n$ be the answer, for a collection of $n$ letters. For $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ let $X_i$ be $1$ if $i$ is a fixed point of a randomly chosen permutation.  $0$ otherwise. Of course the probability that $X_i$ is fixed is $\frac 1n$ so $E[X_i]=\frac 1n$.  As expectations are linear (regardless of independence) we have $$E_n=\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_n]= 1$$

Comment: Pardon! you are right In fact, first ball has $1/10$ to attain its original position. Second ball has $1/9$ if 1st ball is not in position $2$, and $0$ if it is: so $1/9*9/10+0 = 1/10$ : Sorry I did not expect this to be 1/10. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @GCab  That argument is correct, but needlessly complex (extending it to the $37^{th}$ slot out of $43$ will prove very tedious).   Each number has an equal shot of being in slot $i$ so the probability that it ends up being filled by $i$ is $\frac 1n$.

Comment: thanks. Very interestingly, said $h(n,k) = $  n. of $n$-permutations with $k$ fixed points, and $D(n)=h(n,0)$ the derangements, then $$
n! = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {h(n,k)}  = \left[ {0 = n} \right] + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {k\,h(n,k)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)D(k)}  = \left[ {0 = n} \right] + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {n - k} \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)D(k)} 
$$

Comment: @GCab  Not following.  If, say, $n=2$ then of course there is $1$ permutation (or derangement if you prefer) with $0$ fixed points, and another permutation with $2$ fixed points.  Your formula would appear to give $2=2!=(2-0)\binom 20 D(0)+(2-1)\binom 21 D(1)+(2-2)\binom 22 D(2)=0+0+0=0$.  I think your sum ought to read $\sum_{0≤k≤n} \binom nk D(n-k)$

Comment: $D(0)=h(0,0)$ is considered to be $1$, so the above comes $2+0+0=2$ The formulas without $k$ or $(n-k)$ to multiply , and including the one you suggest, are standard known (e.g. "Concrete Mathematics" - pag. 194). The others come from the expected value to be $1$. I verified them with Mupad (at least for $n=0..6$).

Comment: Interesting for our discussion is the para. "Probability Distribution" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers